# по моему исходнику не получается, помогите пожалуйста

Tags: python, python-3.x

На вход программе подается натуральное число nn. Напишите программу, которая для каждого из чисел от 00 до nn (включительно) выводит фразу: «Квадрат числа [число] равен [число]» (без кавычек).

Формат входных данных:
На вход программе подается натуральное число nn.

Формат выходных данных:
Программа должна вывести текст в соответствии с условием задачи.

```
Sample Input 1:

9
Sample Output 1:

Квадрат числа 0 равен 0
Квадрат числа 1 равен 1
Квадрат числа 2 равен 4
Квадрат числа 3 равен 9
Квадрат числа 4 равен 16
Квадрат числа 5 равен 25
Квадрат числа 6 равен 36
Квадрат числа 7 равен 49
Квадрат числа 8 равен 64
Квадрат числа 9 равен 81
```

```
a = int(input())
for i in range(10):
print('Квадрат числа', i , 'равен',a ** 2)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вам надо возводить в квадрат число `i` а не `a`

в цикле `for` надо проходить от `0` до `a` а не до десяти

```
a = int(input())
for i in range(a + 1):
    print('Квадрат числа', i , 'равен',i ** 2)
```

В одну строку

```
[print(f"Квадрат числа {i} равен {i ** 2}") for i in range(int(input()) + 1)]
```

Comment: Failed test #2 of 4. Wrong answer

This is a sample test from the problem statement!

Test input:
1
Correct output:
Квадрат числа 0 равен 0
Квадрат числа 1 равен 1

Your code output:
Квадрат числа 0 равен 0
Квадрат числа 1 равен 1
Квадрат числа 2 равен 4
Квадрат числа 3 равен 9
Квадрат числа 4 равен 16
Квадрат числа 5 равен 25
Квадрат числа 6 равен 36
Квадрат числа 7 равен 49
Квадрат числа 8 равен 64
Квадрат числа 9 равен 81

Comment: @Danis Ок, понятно.